# Why I'm getting org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm having properties/messages file name:

```
messages_en.properties
```

And I have the property inside:

```
country.AF.name=Afghanistan
```

here is the messages class:

[image]

```
 @ApplicationScope
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class Messages {
        
    private ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

    private MessageSourceAccessor accessor;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {               
        messageSource();
        accessor = new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource, Locale.ENGLISH);
        log.info("Messages initialized");
    }

    public String get(String code) {
        return accessor.getMessage(code);
    }
    
    public void messageSource() {
        messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:messages_en.properties");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);        
    }
```

The full error I'm getting is as follow:

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
```

Postman show wrong results, I need to get all the countries:
[image]

Comment: Have a look in the picture I just added.

Comment: I think I missing reload the4 messages file. But I don't know the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the below things message Sources bean configuration

```
messageSource
.setBasename("classpath:messages_en.properties")
```

Comment: MessageSource doesn't have the method

Comment: Check now  that setBasename

Comment: There is no such method

Comment: The class ResourceBundleMessageSource  has setBasename but I don't know hoe to update the Messages class

Comment: <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>

Comment: Add above dependency

Comment: @Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource
      = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    return messageSource;
}

Comment: Now try with above dependency

Comment: i did somthing like this already but without the bean annotation and it works

Comment: Your classpath:messages_en.properties helped

Comment: Welcome, that bean need Come in @Configuration class

Comment: I still have exception, I'm trying to get embedded tomcat log, can't find it

Comment: I'm updating the question

Comment: I shave the follwing already:  spring-boot-starter-validation

Comment: I think I have problem in the Location class, I sending countries with states, I'm updating it now and will post a new question if required. If you update the answer with usage of ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource  I'll accept it for everyone to know.

Comment: In the picture I can see cyclic problem.

Comment: To avoid the cyclic problem Use  JsonManagedReference annotation in parents class  and add 
 JsonBackReference annotation on child class ....

Comment: @JsonManagedReference
    public List<child> items;

Comment: @JsonBackReference
    public Parent owner;